# How to find out when a kernel update was released

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I can see this is the latest kernel for Ubuntu 14.04:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic

But, surprisingly, I cannot see anywhere exactly which day it was released on. Is there a way to discover that? Or is there an apt-get or similar command I can run? (I am hoping I can find this out without installing or downloading the package.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of just tracking what's available, if you can rely on your local repositories to do the work for you, it's quite easy. You can just use `apt-cache` to see what the current `linux-image-generic` meta-package points at. I've fluffed it up so it *just* returns the kernel version.

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache depends linux-image-generic | sed -n '2s/.*: //p'
```

Finding out the package date is a little harder. And more manual.

- Stick the version on the end of: `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/`
  Eg: [`https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic)
- Find your build. Probably from the security repo. That [takes you here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic/3.13.0-37.64).
- Look in the Downloadable Files section for something that ends "produced these files". That'll take you to [the build information page](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/6401410).
- And that's where you find:

  > Started on 2014-09-22
  >   Finished on 2014-09-23 (took 2 hours, 21 minutes, 32.7 seconds)

Pretty exhausting for an otherwise dull bit of information. It's easier to just:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It'll upgrade the kernel if there's a newer version available.

Comment: Thanks; the middle bit of your answer was what I was after. It is no duller or less useful than the information that is easy to find about a package. The most recent EC2 ubuntu AMI, built on 20140927, has the previous kernel (but asks you to upgrade the kernel the first time you run `apt-get upgrade`), so it looks like something went wrong making the AMI.

Comment: P.S. Or there is a reason the .37 kernel should not be used with Amazon EC2...

Answer (score 2):

You can check in this [PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) the kernels for each Ubuntu release.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that would be ideal, but I couldn't work out how to relate the directory names to the kernel package version numbers.